# Concatenate SQL Server stored procedure result with additional text

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concatenation

I'd like to take the result of a stored procedure and concatenate it with additional text in as simple a way as possible.

Something along these lines:

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UserFriendlyText] @Text varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT CASE @Text
     WHEN 'Foo' THEN 'Beginning'
     WHEN 'bar' THEN 'End'
     ELSE 'Text Not Found'
END
END
```

It would be referenced like so:

```
DECLARE @Var1 varchar(100)
SET @Var1 = 'Foo'    
EXEC dbo.sp_UserFriendlyText @Var1 + ' is the best'
```

With the desired result being "Beginning is the best".

It complains my syntax is incorrect.  I've tried adding parenthesis around the exec statement to create precedence, but it still doesn't work.

Because the sproc will be referenced in multiple queries I'd like to run it without the output declaration if at all possible (just to make things cleaner).

System is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a UDF would be a better choice in this situation for the cleanest syntax...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_UserFriendlyText](@Text VARCHAR(100))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ReturnvValue VARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @ReturnvValue = CASE @Text
        WHEN 'Foo' THEN 'Beginning'
        WHEN 'bar' THEN 'End'
        ELSE 'Text Not Found'
    END

    RETURN @ReturnvValue
END
GO
```

Then to call...

```
DECLARE @Var1 VARCHAR(100)
SET @Var1 = 'Foo'
SET @Var1 = dbo.udf_UserFriendlyText(@Var1) + ' is the best'
SELECT @Var1
```

Comment: Didn't even think of using a UDF, but it's clean and simple. Perfect!